# Launch MSI in REINSTALL mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project

I need to launch an MSI depending on the version installed on the target machine.
To elaborate:

- MSI shouldnt install if its version is less than the currently installed version.
- Otherwise it should do REINSTALL using REINSTALLMODE=omus.

I know that this can be done by wrapping the MSI within a bootstrapper application or using cmd to launch MSI.
But could this intelligence be implemented within the MSI itself, so that it appropriately launches itself when I double-click it?

Will LaunchCondition or CustomAction help to achieve this?

I am using Visual Studio Setup Project to build my MSI. Will using WIX help to achieve this?

Thanks,
-Kunal

Comment: What's the problem you think you're solving? You're in Visual Studio setups, just do a RemovePreviousVersions upgrade to replace any older version out there, and this will be a fresh install for new clients too.

Answer (score 0):

The first can be done inside the MSI but the second cannot.  The [MajorUpgrade Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) has the AllowDowngrades and DowngradeErrorMessage attributes that implements a detect and block pattern.

The second isn't possible because it's immutable once the MSI starts.  You need to invoke from  bootstrapper such as burn to achieve this.